# Convert string to unicode - NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Tags: python, unicode

In `python 3.7.3` , I try to do with a string:

```
document_new = unicode(document, "utf-8")
```

but I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

Keep in mind that when I run `print(type(document))` then the output is `<class 'str'>`.

Comment: Python 2 or 3? In Python 3, all strings are unicode.

Comment: If you are using Python 3, `unicode` doesn't exist. Python 2 `str` became Python 3 `bytes`, and Python 2 `unicode` became Python 3 `str`.

Comment: Try this: `document_new = document.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @PoeteMaudit That answer isn't about `unicode`: it is about `unidecode`. The module `unidecode` still exists. It is the `unicode` type that has been renamed to `str` in Python 3.